# JavaFX Marquee se sale del nodo

Tags: javafx, java-8, animación, scroll

Tengo un problema con la animación de tipo "Marquee" en JavaFx. Esta es la situación:
tengo un HBox con tres nodos y en el nodo central tengo un Label con un texto que quiero hacerle la animación, la cual funciona perfectamente, pero cuando va hacia la izquierda y abandona el nodo, necesito que desaparezca y no se vaya mostrando el texto en el siguiente nodod

Os dejo una imagen del problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi declaración del HBox

```
    HBox bill = new HBox(0);
    bill.getChildren().addAll(logoPane,product,total);
    bill.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.web("#FFFFFF"), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
    bill.setHgrow(product, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

La animación:

```
    timelineAnimation = new Timeline();
    final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(productLabel.translateXProperty(), -1000);
    final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2000), kv);
    timelineAnimation.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
```

Y cómo defino mi nodo producto:

```
productLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",30));

    product = new StackPane();
    product.setMaxWidth(2000);
    product.setMaxHeight(100);
    product.setMinWidth(574);
    product.setMinHeight(100);

    product.getChildren().add(productLabel);
    product.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
    product.setAlignment(productLabel, Pos.CENTER);
```

Espero que tengáis suficiente información

Gracias!

Comment: Editada. Perdone la confusión @lois6b .

Comment: Nada, he retirado el voto de cierre. Date una vuelta por el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/) para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento de este sitio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta respuesta me la ha aportado @fabian de la comunidad de StackOverflow.com (inglés). Me limito a ponerla y traducirla por si a alguien le es de interés, a mi me ha funcionado. (Gracias @fabian)

Simplemente añade un `Rectangle` como `clip` para el panel `product` y "bindea" (bind) su tamaño al tamaño del panel:

```
Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
product.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    clip.setWidth(newValue.getWidth());
    clip.setHeight(newValue.getHeight());
});
product.setClip(clip);
```

Ésto te asegurará que ningún descendiente de `product`es dibujado fuera de los límites de éste nodo.